# How was Google recaptcha v2 bypassed several times?

Tags: google, captcha

There are [multiple](https://threatpost.com/google-recaptcha-bypass-technique-uses-googles-own-tools/124006/) reports of a reᴄᴀᴘᴛᴄʜᴀ v2 bypass. Most of the time, the explanation is neural networks services [provided by Google](https://www.kaspersky.com/blog/googles-recaptcha-defeated-by-security-researchers/11880/) or IBM.

But there is something I am failing to understand: for most CAPTCHA(including reCAPTCHA v1) the manually deciphered text is sent directly to the server inside an ʜᴛᴛᴘ header. But with reCAPTCHA v2, the response/ʜᴛᴛᴘ header sent to the server looks like this:

```
g-recaptcha-response:03AJpayVEtSKNOXg7TJwMkmxzLA_HrnWMKm6p0ox6W6hhMcw3Bzxab8ariLgg8Q8wXpUcF8HLkhAd1ixXgNvBDde5ggVXidl3NuHSQcnP4QqJkVvWZ2s4_CQ1lHTw6oNEqXyiBuS3CkiHBhoB5akijJ6ld115K_OWZo6mfB4xz_-I2P36fVqT9VzEUz26wrauN9QZuC6lh80mf-fkxqCPmNYSOcMrHxR33Flby05gzo5cD1B-2FucaoFP11p2svvZrWC_vAjz5bGOzW0DufM2kkdtLIlhzl9GBzm_chyirSJItHGdz0bMuxDYZkRKY8c4gXUmzT09VEgivi032zZnNXtrVA04gXF5yE0tAtnGTwi31hMdzumPoc6GdLdIbvfbXgdyndocCLIph-j9T8ePf3JO8Jfcf6BNcmUKT2SrhZjIAPUOZV2Mg7Qua_s4zNHYx1-NE8zoe9SG-VxuPbx2sjR32ce4oapa6VA
```

even with an audio to text sample. Whatever the method claimed to be used, I am still failing to understand the link between `g-recaptcha-response` HTTP header and human created data.

Recreating the `g-recaptcha-response` one time token seems to be a requirement for all bypass methods. So what is the link between the one time token and a deciphered audio text for example since peoples did reverse engineered it ?
The only thing I understood is everything is client side concerning token generation (no server side requests).

Comment: They are case where the source code of script is available, but in those case, I am failing to find the token generation algorithm inside the script.

Comment: Honestly, it is hard to know, as google does not want us to know. Knowing how it works would make it easier to break. I would assume that there is more data in the response, than just the choices themselves. Maybe mouse movement, time it took and similar. You could try to reverse engineer the script, but it would be a pain: https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/v1524685466525/recaptcha__en.js

Comment: @PeterHarmann what I mean is peoples did reverse engineered it… Obviously. I am failing to understand clear source code of bypass scripts, so I don’t even try with official obfuscated version… At least don’t forget you can upvote.

Comment: @forest Does it not have server side help? I kind of assumed this response is forwarded to google to evaluate. Therefore it could just encode the answers and additional data and evaluate them on googles side. It seems to me to be a bit long for just the answers hashed or otherwise obfuscated.

Comment: @PeterHarmann I suppose I misunderstood.

Comment: @PeterHarmann I checked requests in Dragonfly. Everything is client side.

Comment: Did you not see on the same Threatpost site you linked to , infact even linked from the page you linked to was an article entitled "Google Patches reCAPTCHA Bypass". I suggest you go read that.

Comment: @LittleCode this doesn’t explain how more successful method like unCAPTCHA compute the header sent to the web application from web browser client ?

Comment: Did you look at the python script linked to from the article? https://github.com/eastee/rebreakcaptcha/blob/master/rebreakcaptcha.py It uses selenium, so for the researchers there was no need to fake the execution of anything client side.

Comment: @JonahBenton : then using selenium involve loading all page elements (including ads)… This isn’t a really better way than using cheap labor… Not a good Breaking method…

Comment: Google runs a series of checks to determine that a live browser is running, and the difficulty of the captcha is in part determined by google's known history of the browser. One of the other papers talks about this, and automating around it, including generating false history: https://www.blackhat.com/docs/asia-16/materials/asia-16-Sivakorn-Im-Not-a-Human-Breaking-the-Google-reCAPTCHA-wp.pdf. Regarding the encryption machinery, have you seen this work? https://github.com/neuroradiology/InsideReCaptcha

Comment: @JonahBenton my question isn’t how to detect the correct answer, but how to send the token matching the answer…

Comment: The InsideReCaptcha work says: "This information, along with numeric values hardcoded in the bytecode (forcing a potential bot to read all of it), is sent to the https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/frame page. Look at the M.prototype.Q function to see how the encoding process is realized. Some of information (the one I call xhr2 in the decompiler, which is retrieved in the this.c[this.g] variable − xhr1 is in this.c[this.d]) is also encrypted with XTEA."

Comment: @JonahBenton thank you, but it’s still makes a gap beetween understanding that and generating the values matching the correct answers…

Comment: Yes, there is a big gap there. The level of care taken to obfuscate the recaptcha process by google is clearly very high, so the specific knowledge this question is asking about may not be commodity, unlike nearly all other answers on SO. It may be worth picking up on InsideReCaptcha, seeing how much of that analysis still applies, and raising concrete questions where it doesn't.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  I mean, it looks like people used neural networks to solve the CAPTCHA.  Since this doesn't require screwing with the HTML headers or anything like that, why does the question discuss them?

Comment: @Nat Used them only to recognize images or audio content. The remaining is still done manually like before.

Answer (score 2):

Why reverse engineering the code when you can make it work for you?

It would be sufficient to interact with the rendered web page. For example you could develop a browser extension that waits for the web page to be rendered, downloads the challenge (in this case it was the audio), cracks it (in this case it was slightly obfuscated and sent back to google's own speech recognition engine), inserts the solution in the answer field and finally emulates a mouse click that launches Google's JavaScript to compute the final token.

Source: [Bleeping Computer](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/researcher-breaks-recaptcha-using-googles-speech-recognition-api/)

*p.s. Google's ReCAPTCHA is not very privacy friendly, I suggest to use something else.*

Comment: This seems like the obvious answer; I'm not really sure if I get the original question.  I mean, why'd they talk about HTML headers and whatnot?

Comment: @Nat probably the requester was confused by the fact that the researcher used Python, still it used a Python driver that [relied on Firefox for rendering](https://github.com/eastee/rebreakcaptcha/blob/master/rebreakcaptcha.py).

Comment: @EnosD'Andrea using browser rendering isn’t efficient. I’m now considering this script as an exception compared to other ones which likely solved the underlining problems through reverse engineering.

Comment: @user2284570 if you use a remote service, the randering time might not be the largest. You might also have to find another way to crack the audio: the  original researcher reported that his solution does not work anymore since when Google increased the number of digit and noise of the challenge.

Comment: @EnosD'Andrea Not with high latency connections : you download many non required things in this technic (takes 20 to 30s in my place whereas a captcha is downloaded in 1s or less). In fact I asked this question in order to find a way to bypass recognizing requirement even with bot handling.

Comment: @user2284570 I am confident Google's script does not check the integrity of the web page, otherwise it would fail when the page is changed by its author. In your shoes I would try restricting which contents are loaded by the rendering engine and stick to external rendering (possibly remote), otherwise you'd have to start over whenever Google changes implementation details.